# Where is the full list of exemplar cities for English in the CLDR time zone xml?

Tags: timezone, cldr

There are a couple exemplar cities and metazone names in `core/common/main/en.xml` from CLDR, however, the full list is not included in en.xml like there is in all the other languages.

Why is this and where do I find the entire list of exemplar cities for English?

Comment: Thank you Matt! I was hoping you would stop by. I'm trying to design a time zone system for a project and trying to figure out all the pieces by using standard practices with IANA DB and CLDR.

Comment: I'm not very confident with CLDR, this will help you? [this json](https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-dates-full/blob/master/main/fr/timeZoneNames.json) or [this list of cities](http://publications.europa.eu/code/en/en-5000500.htm) or [this from the standard](http://cldr.unicode.org/translation/country-names)

Comment: Thanks Stefano. I'm specifically looking for something in the xml format as seen in core/common/main since all the other languages are in there. I looked at en_US.xml and en_US_POSIX.xml but those don't contain the same information.

Comment: Ok, i see. Let me check if i can found out something, looks like you are not the one reporting this: [have a look](http://unicode.org/pipermail/cldr-users/2015-September/000361.html)

Comment: Thanks. Similar, but I am focused on time zones.

Comment: what about [this](http://unicode.org/cldr/trac/browser/tags/release-28/common/main/en.xml) ? Seems complete to you?

Comment: So if you search the tag exemplarCity, you will notice that the en.xml has very few of them compared to all the other languages. For example, if you open up fr.xml, you will see the full list of exemplarCity. Compare this file with en.xml.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100616/discussion-between-stefano-saitta-and-user224579).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer in the [CLDR bug tracker](http://unicode.org/cldr/trac/ticket/5563).

Comment: Hi @user224579, can you share the answer you found? As far as I can see the bug says that they have decided not to move anything to root.xml from en.xml. It doesn't say why there is limited data in en.xml or where to find full data.